# How to backup files with a certain file extension

Tags: windows-7, backup

I want to backup files with a specific extension to a NAS.

I know some of the cloud based applications like Mozy can do that.

How can I achieve that without a cloud-based tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FreeFileSync](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freefilesync/) is a great backup free & open source software.

It can use filters (include and/or exclude) with wildcards such as *.pdf.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From seeing the screenshot on [this site](http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/BackupPCEditConfig.html), I would assume that [BackupPC](http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/) can do what you want.

I've previously recommended it here: [Take automatic backups of all computers on network](https://serverfault.com/a/213369/61246)